# How do I configure Ghost in in dev and production to make a json data available via url to load with d3.json?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, config, ghost-blog

Hello I've built a custom Ghost theme for a blog I'm starting and I would like create a map on a static page using d3 but I am stuck loading the geo json data. D3.json requires the data be available via a URL and I haven't been able to figure out how to configure Ghost to make that possible.

The first thing I tried was to put the custom.geo.json file in

```
/content/themes/my-theme/assets/images/custom.geo.json
```

Which I realize is a silly place but I have loaded images and icons from that directory so it seemed accessible. I tried putting it in

```
/content/themes/my-theme/
```

my conifg.development.json looks like this:

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:2368/",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "sqlite3",
    "connection": {
      "filename": "/Users/allisonmadigan/blog/dev/content/data/ghost-local.db"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "local",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/Users/allisonmadigan/blog/dev/content"
  }

route.yaml: 
routes:
  /:
    controller: channel
    data: page.home
    template: 
      - home
collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /blog/{slug}/
    template: 
      - index

taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```

My Javascript code is

```
// get map data
d3.json(
  "/data/custom.geo.json", function(json) {
    //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
    countriesGroup = svg.append("g").attr("id", "map");
    // add a background rectangle
    countriesGroup
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
```

The error I get is:

```
d3.min.js:7 GET http://localhost:2368/data/custom.geo.json/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I even tried in development starting a python SimpleHTTPServer but then javascript tried to go to

`http://localhost:2368/http://localhost:8000/blog/dev/content/themes/mytheme/data/custom.geojson`

I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also posted to the Ghost community and a very nice person there had the solution.  He said Ghost doesn't send json files from themes for security reasons. He recommended using "the content-type feature in Dynamic Routing to “render” a template (which is really a json file)."

So now my route.yaml file looks like

```
routes:
  /:
    controller: channel
    data: page.home
    template: 
      - home
  /data/geo/:
    template: 
    - geo
    content-type: json
collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /blog/{slug}/
    template: 
      - index

taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```

I renamed custom.geo.json to geo.hbs and left in the theme folder.

and my js code is :

```
d3.json(
  "/data/geo/", function(json) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the ghost routing and you've got nginx as a reverse  proxy in front of ghost you can serve the json using the `location` directive.

See the config sketch.

```
server {
     ...
     ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
location /data/geo.json {
    alias path/to/geo.json;
}
```